# Filling missing values

Tags: r, statistics, missing-data

I have a dataset like this

```
 4  6 18 12  4  5
 2  9  0  3 NA 13
11 NA  6  7  7  9
```

How I can fill the missing values using R?

Comment: However you like.  What have you tried/searched for?  What do you want the new values to be?

Comment: @GSee, the new values have to be related with the column and row.

Comment: @george. I have no idea what you mean

Comment: @plannapus just add your answer it's better.

Comment: @george if it is not just a pure R-question but rather something like "How can I impute missing values in my data set?" the answer will be "it depends on the nature of your data". In the meantime you could check out the Imputation section in http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/OfficialStatistics.html for available packages in R.

Comment: The [**zoo**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) has lots of ways to deal with missing data. `na.locf`, `na.spline`, `na.aggregate`, `na.fill`, `na.approx`, `na.trim`, ...

Comment: Could you please give some examples about how you want to fill those missing values?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to replace your NAs with a fixed value (`a` being your dataset):

```
a[is.na(a)] <- 0 #For instance
```

If you want to replace them with a value that's a function of the row number and the column number (as you suggest in your comment):

```
#This will replace them by the sum of their row number and their column number:
a[is.na(a)] <- rowSums(which(is.na(a), arr.ind=TRUE))

#This will replace them by their row number:
a[is.na(a)] <- which(is.na(a), arr.ind=TRUE)[,1]

#And this by their column number:
a[is.na(a)] <- which(is.na(a), arr.ind=TRUE)[,2]
```